# Filtered html with class attribute not being stripped?

Tags: 7, input-formats

How to extend "filtered html" by ability of using class attribute? I can't let user have full html, but classes seem to be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [Wysiwyg filter](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter) module in combination with the wysiwyg module for this. The module allows you to define exactly what properties to allow, what elements, classes etc. It takes a little time to set up, but the added control is well worth it imo.

Comment: telling by the screenshot(http://drupal.org/files/issues/wysiwyg_filter_settings.png) it looks it might do the job. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found way of implementing of filtering system:
http://definitivedrupal.org/node/90

but I still hope there's easier way like just a checkbox [x] don't filter class attribute.